# Spring AspectJ load time weaving javaagent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, aspectj

I want to use AspectJ to add a filter whenever a Hibernate session is opened. I created an aspect and tested it for my own classes and it worked, however for the Hibernate session it does not do anything.

I created a META-INF/aop.xml in the resources:

```
<aspectj>

<weaver options="-Xreweavable -verbose -showWeaveInfo">
    <include within="immo.api.config.multitenancy.TestAspect"/>
    <include within="org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.SessionBuilderImpl"/>
</weaver>

<aspects>
    <aspect name="immo.api.config.multitenancy.TestAspect"/>
</aspects>
```

When I start my programm, i get the following exception:

```
... Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-instrument-{version}.jar
```

I followed those tutorials:

[Tutorial 1](https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2020/10/17/multi-tenancy-with-spring-boot-part5/)
[Tutorial 2](http://cyriltech.blogspot.com/2017/03/how-to-enable-hibernate-filter-using.html)

I saw that I have to pass JVM arguments as the exception also tells, so I tried to do the following in the build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-javaagent:spring-instrument.jar", "-javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar"]
```

the applicationDefaultJvmrgs are never used according to IntelliJ and i still get the same exception.

So can anybody help me to pass the JvmArgs correctly in gradle? Or, even better, tell me how to get the job done using a custom LoadTimeWeaver?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Maybe it was unclear. Problem is that the aop.xml is never used and I just need to know how to tell the jvm to use javaagent with gradle

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for the interesting question. Like this, with a bunch of little snippets, the question is concise, but unfortunately nobody can reproduce your problem. Due to the complex interplay of Gradle, Spring, AspectJ, Hibernate, I suggest you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, then maybe someone can find out what is wrong and help you answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my

https://guypaddock.github.io/posts/aspectj-native-syntax-with-spring-ltw-and-gradle/

This approach fixes my problem.